# keeping image contained within another image.

Tags: css

How can I keep a close button contained inside an image even is I change the img size using jquery

```
#full_image {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
left: 0px;
top:10px;
position: relative;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 9;
}

#full_image img {
left: 20px;
width: 339px;
height: 211px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#full_image .close{
 background: url("http://www.sobral.ce.gov.br/saudedafamilia/close.jpg") no-repeat;
 top: 5px; 
 right: 0px;  
cursor: pointer;
height: 29px;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;    
width: 29px;
z-index: 999;
}


<div id="full_image"><img src="http://coe.berkeley.edu/forefront/fall2005/images/woz1.jpg" />
<span> <a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
 </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FPTHu/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS:

```
#full_image {
    position: relative;
}

#full_image span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This tells the span to be a positioned relatively to `#full_image`, and stick to top right of it.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what "close button contained inside an image" means. I would have tried to put my image and button like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img id="myImage"></img>
    <button id="myButton" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myImage {
    position: relative;
}

#myButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: ???;
    left: ???;
}
```

jQuery:
You have to calculate where to place your button (what you should give the CSS-attributes for f ex `top:` and `left:` )